# pyside6 update webview url works only in app.py but not as imported class

Tags: python-3.x, pyside6, pyqt6

I want to click on a item in a QListView "widget_list_files" (which is a file-path to a pdf) and update the QWebEngineView "view" to show the pdf.
It works fine if I put everything in the same app.py, but if I move it to a separate file and import the class the QListView is populated but the click event gets ignored.
A funny behavior is, that if set some break points and start the vscode debugging it also works with the the import O.o

app.py

```
from modm.functions.cms import cms

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.file_path = '/home/user/Downloads'

        layout_cms = QHBoxLayout()

        # Files Layout
        layout_files = QVBoxLayout()

        layout_files_search = QHBoxLayout()

        search_input_text = QLineEdit()
        search_input_text.setMaxLength(10)
        search_input_text.setPlaceholderText("Enter your text")
        layout_files_search.addWidget(search_input_text)

        search_button_search = QPushButton("Search")
        layout_files_search.addWidget(search_button_search)

        self.widget_list_files = QListView()
        self.widget_list_files.clicked.connect(self.open_document)
        self.model_files = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model_files.setNameFilterDisables(False)
        self.model_files.setFilter(QDir.Files)
        self.model_files.setNameFilters(["*.pdf"])

        layout_files.addLayout(layout_files_search)
        layout_files.addWidget(self.widget_list_files)

        layout_cms.addLayout( layout_files,stretch=2)

        # Document Layout
        self.view = QWebEngineView()
        self.view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        self.view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PdfViewerEnabled, True)
        layout_document = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_document.addWidget(self.view)

        # Document Layout -> buttons
        layout_document_buttons = QHBoxLayout()
        document_button_merge = QPushButton("Merge")
        layout_document_buttons.addWidget(document_button_merge)

        layout_document.addLayout(layout_document_buttons)
        layout_cms.addLayout(layout_document,stretch=3)

        self.model_files.setRootPath(self.file_path)
        self.widget_list_files.setModel(self.model_files)
        self.widget_list_files.setRootIndex(self.model_files.index(self.file_path))
        self.widget_cms = QWidget()
        self.widget_cms.setLayout(layout_cms)

        content_cms = cms()
        # Tab Menu
        tab_menu = QTabWidget()
        tab_menu.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.West)
        tab_menu.setMovable(True)
        # here I use the imported version
        tab_menu.addTab(content_cms.widget_cms, 'CMS')
        # here I use code from this file
        tab_menu.addTab(self.widget_cms, 'Merge')
        self.setCentralWidget(tab_menu)

    def open_document(self,index):
        self.view.setUrl(f"file://{self.model_files.filePath(index)}")
def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

cms.py

```
class cms():

    def __init__(self):
        self.file_path = '/home/user/Downloads'

        layout_cms = QHBoxLayout()

        # Files Layout
        layout_files = QVBoxLayout()

        layout_files_search = QHBoxLayout()

        search_input_text = QLineEdit()
        search_input_text.setMaxLength(10)
        search_input_text.setPlaceholderText("Enter your text")
        layout_files_search.addWidget(search_input_text)

        search_button_search = QPushButton("Search")
        layout_files_search.addWidget(search_button_search)

        self.widget_list_files = QListView()
        self.widget_list_files.clicked.connect(self.open_document)
        self.model_files = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model_files.setNameFilterDisables(False)
        self.model_files.setFilter(QDir.Files)
        self.model_files.setNameFilters(["*.pdf"])

        layout_files.addLayout(layout_files_search)
        layout_files.addWidget(self.widget_list_files)

        layout_cms.addLayout( layout_files,stretch=2)

        # Document Layout
        self.view = QWebEngineView()
        self.view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        self.view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PdfViewerEnabled, True)
        layout_document = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_document.addWidget(self.view)

        # Document Layout -> buttons
        layout_document_buttons = QHBoxLayout()
        document_button_merge = QPushButton("Merge")

        layout_document.addLayout(layout_document_buttons)
        layout_cms.addLayout(layout_document,stretch=3)

        self.model_files.setRootPath(self.file_path)
        self.widget_list_files.setModel(self.model_files)
        self.widget_list_files.setRootIndex(self.model_files.index(self.file_path))
        self.widget_cms = QWidget()
        self.widget_cms.setLayout(layout_cms)

    def open_document(self,index):
        # if I set the breakpointn in the line below and randomly somewhere in __init__ it also works in this version in debug mode
        self.view.setUrl(f"file://{self.model_files.filePath(index)}")
```

I move the exact same code from the app.py to the cms.py and I exprected it to work like it did in the app.py, which means that the pdf file which is an item in the QListView "widget_list_files" gets displayed in the QWebEngineView "view".

Comment: `content_cms` gets out of scope and garbage collected, with its `open_document` function along with it. Change to `self.content_cms = cms`, or, better, make it inherit from QWidget and directly add **it** to the tab (also remove its `self.widget_cms` and use `self.setLayout(layout_cms)`.

Comment: thank you! It works like a charm.
if anybody else is looking for it, I inherited it by 
`class cms(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(cms, self).__init__()`
and called it with `tab_menu.addTab(cms(), 'CMS')`

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution thanks [musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante).

changes to app.py

```
# wrong and completely removed:
# content_cms = cms()
# Tab Menu
tab_menu = QTabWidget()
tab_menu.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.West)
tab_menu.setMovable(True)
# wrong:
# tab_menu.addTab(content_cms.widget_cms, 'CMS')
# right:
tab_menu.addTab(cms(), 'CMS')
self.setCentralWidget(tab_menu)
```

changes to cms.py

```
# wrong:
#class cms():
# right: inherit QWidget
class cms(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        # init QWidget 
        super(cms, self).__init__()
        ...
        # wrong
        #self.widget_cms = QWidget()
        #self.widget_cms.setLayout(layout_cms)
        # right:
        self.setLayout(layout_cms)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.